# Create C project by default in Clion

Tags: c, cmake, clion

I have been using Clion in Windows where i get an option to choose what type of project i wish to create (c/c++) but in Mac it doesn't ask me to choose between the type of project. It is set `c++` by default. However renaming `.cpp` to `.c` again and again, following this [How to create a C project with CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177390/how-to-create-a-c-project-with-clion) doesn't seem like a cool idea (time consuming). So, is there any option in setting/ preferences in which I can set `cLion` to create C project by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a C project with CLion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177390/how-to-create-a-c-project-with-clion)

Comment: @KristerAndersson i mentioned that link in my post please read the post before downvoting

Comment: that post doesn't solve my purpose, he has some different thing & i am asking something different

Comment: I haven't downvoted, why do you assume that?

Comment: @KristerAndersson sorry my assumption went wrong. But whosoever did downvoted my post have no reason to do that. People are misusing their rights to vote here on stackoverflow. Stoping new people like me to learn :(

Answer (score 3):

Greetings from germany,

unfortunately there is still no project wizard implemented.
Have a look at this answer:

"You can create C++ project and them rename main.cpp file for now. In the future we are probably planning C project in project creating wizard."
- posted by Anastasia Kazakova  on 17 Oct 2015, 16:56.

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4749

Answer (score 0):

I have just found an answer to this question. JetBrains has yet not introduced this feature to their IDE.

They will include this feature in the next update: [see this link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-372)