# clion change default project template

Tags: c, templates, clion

Hi I program in c and I like using clion. Is there a way to change how the default files it creates in a new project? I would like it to create a main.c and the make file to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [How to create a C project with CLion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177390/how-to-create-a-c-project-with-clion). It's not possible to create a C project by default, but you could use the info of that post to prepare CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 2016.3.2 you can choose language (C or C++) and project type (Executable or Library) when creating a new project.

> (Though this was in CodeBlocks for example for as long as I remember)) And I still never figured out whether I can create my own "project". Well IMHO CLion clearly sucks in this way if compared to CodeBlocks where I CAN WRITE MY SCRIPT FOR ALMOST EVERYTHING and customize the IDE this way((()

https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/12/clion-2016-3-2-eap/#prj_templates